# Django - AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'environment'

Tags: python, django, macos, visual-studio-code, pylint

In the context of learning Django, I need to populate Sqlite with random data using Faker module.

Several models have been created under models.py :

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name

class Webpage(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

To randomly populate these models, I'm using the following script (populate_first_app.py):

```
import os
os.environment.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','first_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

##FAKE POP SCRIPT
import random
from first_app.models import AccessRecord,Webpage,Topic
from faker import Faker


fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['Search','Social','Marketplace','News','Games']

def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t

def populate(N=5):
    for entry in range(N):
        top = add_topic()
        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()

        webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic=top,url=fake_url,name=fake_name)[0]

        acc_rec = AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(name=webpg,date=fake_date)[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('populating script!')
    populate(20)
    print('populating complete')
```

When I'm running populate_first_app.py, I got the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'environment'

Using Visual Studio Code (v1.39.2), I'm stuck.

Visual code is highlighting error on following lines:

```
t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
```

> Class 'Topic' has no 'objects' memberpylint(no-member)

I installed pylint using the following command:

```
pip3 install pylint-django
```

But still stuck.

Comment: try `os.environ` instead of `os.environment`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call should be

```py
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','first_project.settings')
```

For more details you can see previous questions, like this one:
[Is it safe to use os.environ.setdefault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047621/is-it-safe-to-use-os-environ-setdefault)